# Macros in clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I wrote some [simple dsl](https://github.com/farisnasution/juggler) for validating a map, what it can do:

```
(ns foo.validator)

(defrule cannot-foo
  {:message "Value is %s. It cannot equal to string foo"}
  [value]
  (not (= value "foo")))

(defvalidator cannot-foo-validator
  :name [[cannot-foo]])

(cannot-foo-validator {:name "foo"}) ;; {:error <message here>}
```

Under the hood, it binds a function to a given symbol, in this is case `cannot-foo` and `cannot-foo-validator`.

How can I use it on clojurescript? I did exactly like in the clojurescript wiki:

```
(ns cljs.myfoo.core
  (:require-macros [foo.validator :as f]))
```

It compiles without warning, but if I start to use it:

```
(ns cljs.myfoo.core
  (:require-macros [foo.validator :as f]))

(cannot-foo-validator {:name "foo"})
```

When compiling, it complaints with `No such namespace: foo.validator .....`.

Comment: Is `foo` included in your project.clj?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `foo.validator` is in a `.clj` or `.cljc` file.